# How can I create a triangle pointer in Vuetify v-menu component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there a way to add triangle pointer to `v-menu` component in Vuetify 2.x?

I mean on this common detail on the web pages (eg. this screenshot is from github):

[image]

I have sample code [here](https://codepen.io/milost1982/pen/qBEjxrw) with the menu that shows as dropdown when button is clicked. I manage to add margin to the menu of `40px` via CSS so it's pushed down. This will provide some space for the triangle, but how can I add this triangle pointer like its' on github?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Codepen solution](https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/NWPgywg?editors=1100)

I belive you need something like this:

```css
.my-menu {
  margin-top: 40px;
  contain: initial;
  overflow: visible;
}
.my-menu::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  width: 10px; 
  height: 13px; 
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #fff;
}
```

Effect:

[image]

**Note**: Here is an explanation of how it works: [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Answer (score 1):

Specifically concerning vuetify, you would use the `activator` slot and a `v-model` to determine the state of the menu:

```
<v-menu v-model="menu" ...>
   <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn 
        icon
        v-on="on">
        <v-icon>mdi-plus>
        <v-icon v-if="menu">mdi-menu-up</v-icon>
        <v-icon v-else>mdi-menu-up</v-icon>
      </v-btn>          
   </template>
</v-menu>
```

Make sure you bind `v-model` attribute here to a data property within the containing component definition.

**sidenote**

I'm not entirely sure what putting 2 icons inside of a `<v-btn icon` will result in. You may have to tweak it a bit with flex for the layout to work correctly.

Comment: There is the `mdi-menu-down` icon. But I think he asked about the triangle (pointing up) on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.my-menu {
  margin-top: 36px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.my-menu .v-list::before {
  right: 10px;
  top: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}
```